# Using Ninject with objectdatasource in asp.net webforms?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ninject, objectdatasource

I am trying to use Ninject 3 in my asp.net webforms application. It works fine except some pages that contains `ObjectDataSource`, the `Select` method of the `ObjectDataSource` throws a `NullReferenceException`. My code is as follows :

`Web.Admin.Grades.aspx`:

```
<asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
                    EnablePaging="true" TypeName="Web.Admin.Grades"
                    SelectMethod="GetData" SelectCountMethod="GetDataCount"
                    StartRowIndexParameterName="StartRowIndex" MaximumRowsParameterName="MaximumRows">
                    <SelectParameters>
                        <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchTxtBox" Type="String" Name="SearchKeyWord" PropertyName="Text" />
                    </SelectParameters>
                </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

`Web.Admin.Grades.cs`:

```
[Inject]
public IGradesRepository _Grades { get; set; }

public IList GetData(string SearchKeyWord, int StartRowIndex, int MaximumRows)
{
    return _Grades.GetGrades(SearchKeyWord, StartRowIndex, MaximumRows);
}

public int GetDataCount(string SearchKeyWord)
{
    return _Grades.GetGradesCount(SearchKeyWord);
}
```

Comment: Stacktrace and some more info as to how its all wired up and what you've tried would help  (not a lot of people use ODS and if you can meet people half way they can help)

Comment: I start debugging the page and the injection happens but GetData method invoked _Grades is null, What happened?

Comment: I dunno - I'm not there :) Why do you think Ninject has been asked to inject into Web.Admin.Grades ? Ninject needs to have a reason to be be touching your instance - how are you configuring Ninject, what modules are you using. Show some of the wiring etc.

Comment: Web.Admin.Grades.cs is the codebehind file for the page Grades.aspx as in my previous comment when the page is called I start debugging and the property injection was called till now everything is ok but then the Select Method of ObjectDataSource is called which inside I use the injected property to get the data the property seems to be null, Am I supposed not to put the select method in the codebehind file or what I am doing wrong ?

Comment: Its what happens before your code that's obviously going wrong. How are you referencing Ninject. Can you link to the approach you are using to inject Ninject with ASP.NET ? What ASP.NET Version, What Ninject version. Wild guess: You have not told your page class to derive from the correct base. I'm not going to do any more guessing until you expand on how you're using Ninject

Comment: Thanks @Ruben Bartelink but no guessing required I am sorry I did not tell from the beginning  that I used Ninject 3 from Nuget gallery with asp.net 4.5 but I figured out the problem that I was not understand how ObjectDataSource is working but I read this http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.objectdatasource.selectmethod.aspx and solve the problem by pass the ObjectInstance in OnObjectCreating event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry for misunderstanding I solve the problem 
as follows

```
 <asp:ObjectDataSource ID="ObjectDataSource1" runat="server"
                EnablePaging="true" TypeName="Domain.Abstract.IGradesRepository"
                SelectMethod="GetGrades" SelectCountMethod="GetGradesCount"   OnObjectCreating="ObjectDataSource1_ObjectCreating"
                StartRowIndexParameterName="StartRowIndex" MaximumRowsParameterName="MaximumRows">
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:ControlParameter ControlID="SearchTxtBox" Type="String" Name="SearchKeyWord"  PropertyName="Text" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:ObjectDataSource>
```

and Web.Admin.Grades.cs:

```
[Inject]
    public IGradesRepository _Grades { get; set; }
protected void ObjectDataSource1_ObjectCreating(object sender, ObjectDataSourceEventArgs e)
    {
        e.ObjectInstance = _Grades;
    }
```